# insert(X, [], [X]). inserting into a last position

Tags: prolog

this predicate is for inserting a value into a last position in a list:

```
 insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|T]):-insert(X, T, [T|X]).
```

i get 'false', when this query be executed:

```
?- insert(15, [16, 14, 9], R).
```

why, and how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is not possible to insert element `X` at the end of the list `[H|T]` and get as result the same list `[H|T]`, as established by the second clause in the definition of the predicate `insert/3`.

Clearly, the resulting list must be different from the original one and that difference must be in its tail (hence, the tail of the resulting list must be denoted by a diffrent variable, say `U`). Moreover, the new list `U` must be the result of the insertion of the element `X` at the end of the list `T`.

Thus, the correct definition of the predicate `insert/3` is:

```
insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|U]):- 
    insert(X, T, U).
```

Example:

```
?- insert(15,  [16, 14, 9], R).
R = [16, 14, 9, 15] ;
false
```